# Adobe editor PDF file form add a field to show image using PHP script

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, php-pdftk

I want to add an image on PDF file form using PHP script.
I have tried it by adding image field in PDF file and send image path using PHP script for that field, but it's not working.
I am using php-pdftk library to edit PDF form field.
But having issue to add image file in PDF form.

Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks

Comment: I suppose sample code you're using would be helpful for someone who knows what's up.

Comment: It does work when i send image path in variable.

Sending data as :

  'EngSign1'=>'UK.png',

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried (=your code). Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: @anjudhiman I tried your solution and it does not work for me. do you use fillForm function ?